# Trouble using tuple along with other strings when passing them to .format in Python within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have the following TOML:

```
[gps]
measurement = "gps"
tags = ["lat", "lon", "alt"]
limit = 10
```

which translates to the following dictionary in Python:

```
{
  "gps": {
       "measurement": "gps",
       "tags": [ "lat", "lon", "alt"],
       "limit": 10
}
```

I have a class where I wish to create a member function `read_gps` as follows:

1. get the `**kwargs` from above dict
2. currently, just print the following string:
    `select "lat", "lon", "alt", from "gps" limit 10`

### code

```
class dbClass:
    def __init__(self, db=None, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs # this kwargs is different from the above kwargs
        # do some initialization stuff here

     def read_gps(self, **kwargs):
        # pass the above mentioned dict here
        # instance_dbClass.read_gps(gps_dict)

        _data = kwargs
        _tags = kwargs.get('tags')

        print('select "{}","{}","{}" from "{}" limit {}'.format(*_tags,
                          _data.get('measurement'), 
                          _data.get('limit'))
        )
```

But I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

On the contrary, if i remove the `measurement` and `limit` it would work fine.

What is a pythonic way to achieve this? should i create two different strings and then in the end concatenate them?

### Trial

```
query = """
        select "{}", "{}", "{}" from "{}" limit {}
        """.format(_tags[0], _tags[1], _tags[2], _data.get('measurement'),
                   _data.get('limit'))
print(query)
```

works however it there a way to use the `*` unpacking for tuple within the `.format()` along with the other values

Comment: Works just fine for me.

Comment: do you mean with the `*` ?

Comment: Yes, What is your python version ? 3.6 ?

Comment: I am using 3.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will work in Python version 3.5+, following [Pep 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). If you have to use a version lower than 3.5, you can use named parameters:

```
print(select "{}","{}","{}" from "{measurement}" limit {limit}'.format(*_tags, measurement=measurement, limit=limit))
```

Alternatively, join the `_tags` into a single string first:

```
print('select "{}" from "{}" limit {}'.format('","'.join(_tags), measurement, limit))
```

The second option will work even if the length of `_tags` changes.